# How to make an alphabetized menu on Drupal?

Tags: drupal, menu

Could anyone tell me -- or point me to a thread -- that shows how to make an alphabetized, horizontal menu of book pages, listing entries made by users on my site? And how to make entries regarding topic be automatically added to a page of links about that topic? Or if it's a new topic, it's added to the page's links of topics, where now there's a new topic and entry (and of course, any new entries from that point on are added to that topic's list of entries, that you'll access by clicking that topic?)

If I'm confusing you, please see two examples of what I'm trying to do:

1) [Here](http://mp3raid.com) (a music site), where at the top of the screen, the menu goes horizontally, and reads '0-9 A B C D E F', etc. ... when you click any one of the numbers/letters -- let's say 'A', for example --, it brings up a page of all entries starting with 'A'. Then, each 'A' entry -- let's say 'Alabama' is one -- is a link to all pages, media, etc. on the site about 'Alabama'.

From the new entries side, when users type or upload media of any 'A' artist, it eventually is automatically added to this page's list of links to 'A' artists on the site. For example, if the topic 'Alabama' had two entries before the user enters a new one, 'Alabama' would now show links to 3 entries when you click on the link on the page.

Is this possible with Drupal?

Example #2) is a page on Drupal.org ... under 'Alphabetize' and you'll see the same kind of menu : A|B|C|D|E, etc. When you click on any of the letters, it brings you to that alphabet section on the page. I'd much prefer each letter to have its own dedicated page of entries, instead of all of them being on one page ... but if that's too hard to do, I'd have to concede, and have all letters' entries on one page (but it would be a VERY long page!)

It doesn't NECESSARILY have to be a horizontal menu like these two examples; I just like the appearance and space-saving aspects of it, rather than a vertical menu, (i.e. 'A B C', etc. going up and down in a column or block).

An added perk would be, so that there aren't duplicate entries on the same topic but with different spellings, maybe having a drop-down list menu when people are adding entries ... so they'd just scroll down this drop-down list, select who they want to add an entry on, and make the entry...? As you can probably tell, it's a wiki (I've already downloaded all the relevant wiki modules, as explained on the web page 'How to make a wiki with Drupal).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Views, you can set up glossary mode as an attachment, to achieve [this](http://www.thegalleryguide.co.uk/galleries/a-z/all) kind of thing:

I think if you use ctools module you can have a drop-down as well

[This](http://evolvingweb.ca/story/building-glossary-style-view-drupal) is the first tutorial I found, but I'm sure there are more: